# Please I want to Restructure this php URL to SEO friendly URL

Tags: seo, url, php, blog

I have this is the listing page: `<div class="group"><a href="/category?id=<?php echo $data->slug;?>"><?php echo $data->title; ?></a></div>`

I have this https://example.com/category/?id=slug

but I want this https://example.com/category/slug-id

Then I have this in the /category/index.php

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
    {$uid = htmlentities(stripslashes(strip_tags(trim($pid))));}
try {$stmt = $db->prepare("select * from answers where ans_slug =:pid");
        $stmt->execute(array(':pid' => $pid));
            $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
if($row['ans_slug'] == '' || empty($pid)){
    header('Location: ./');
    exit;
}

Please help
```

Comment: Cross-posting is [not allowed on the Stack Exchange network](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068).

Comment: Have check the solutions, none worked for me